# Xaml Glyphs with arabic text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, arabic

I have problem to show this text "لله" with Glyphs in xaml. 
Neither of the two pieces of code show the correct string.
Please help me to find the right UnicodeString and how to get it.

```
Glyphs FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\arial.TTF" FontRenderingEmSize="40" UnicodeString="ﻪﻠﻟ" Fill="Black" OriginX="100" OriginY="200"

Glyphs FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\arial.TTF" FontRenderingEmSize="40" UnicodeString="لله" Fill="Black" OriginX="100" OriginY="100"
```

Comment: Try using the unicode extended Arial font: arialuni.ttf. I think that that glyph is not in the regular font font file

Comment: This don't depend on the font

Comment: I found that I can use Indices in Glyphs instead of UnicodeString, but ho I can convert  "لله" in a int index, because it is not a single char (the UTF-32 Encoding is 0xFDF2, the decomposition in chars is ا (U+0627) - ل (U+0644) - ل (U+0644) - ه (U+0647))

Comment: The syntax showed is exactly the same as the one used in the Microsoft XPS/oxps file  format (ECMA-388). Maybe there are clues there to understand how to manage diacritics positions. From what I can read, you can pass a glyph or add glyphs pre or post: `UnicodeString="&#xbaa;&#xbcb;&#xba4;&#xbc1;"
Indices="(2:3)94;76;88;(2:1)162"`